# How can I make API calls on click with different categories in React using Axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I am trying to get api call on click, but I'm stuck with my console just showing null. I want on different items clicks, different api categories would be called.

```
 const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${url}${category}`)
      .then(function (response: any) {
        console.log(response.data.meals);
      })
      .catch(function (error: any) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [category]);

  const onClickHandler = (e: any) => {
    setCategory(e.target.value);
  };
```

```
<li value="Seafood" onClick={onClickHandler}>
     Seafood
</li>
```

I was expecting like filter buttons to click, and then items would show up based on the filter you click.

Comment: Why don't you just use the API in the click handler, and then use a `useState` hook to manage the resulting API data?

Comment: is your url correct? shouldn't it be something like `${url}/${category}` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` property of a `li` element is reserved, and it tells the order of the `li` in its parent `ol`, as you can read on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#attr-value):

> This integer attribute indicates the current ordinal value of the list item as defined by the `<ol>` element. The only allowed value for this attribute is a number...

You would wanna use a [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), which will work with your attempt and is made for handling clicks. You could nest it in your `li`. But if, for some reason, you want only the `li`, I would suggest a data attribute to avoid confusion:

```
const onClickHandler = (e: any) => {
  setCategory(e.target.getAttribute("data-value"));
};
```

```
<li data-value="Seafood" onClick={onClickHandler}>
    Seafood
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know much but maybe it can work like this, I apologize if it is wrong.**

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (category) {
      axios
        .get(`{url}${category}`)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data.meals);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }, [category]);

  const onClickHandler = (e) => {
    setCategory(e.target.getAttribute('value'));
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      <li value="Seafood" onClick={onClickHandler}>
        Seafood
      </li>
      {/* Add more li elements with different categories and onClickHandler */}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is semantically incorrect. This `value` property is reserved, and it has a meaning to browsers. Do not use it this way. Check the other answer, please.